# angular 4 fails to build for production

Tags: angular

trying ng build --prod throws

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/cdk/platform/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25616:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25404:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25385:14)
    at /Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at extractProgramSymbols (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24240:79)
    at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23796:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:32:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:73:30)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular-material/dbs_revenue_import/revenue-import/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:391:4
```

i tried to delete node_modules but that did not help

Comment: does it work for dev build

Comment: no same error using ng build or ng build --dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

npm install @angular/material@latest --save

npm install @angular/cdk@latest --save

Comment: it did update those packages but i still hit the same error

Comment: try: npm ls --depth=0 to list the dependencies of your project. If there are any errors with dependencies, they should appear at the bottom of the list or be noted in some way.

In the past, I've had to npm install --save a specific version of a package. It's saying it's expecting version 3 so you'd need to npm install --save packagename@3 It could also be a lacking peer dependency in which case, just install the needed packages. Either way npm ls --depth=0 is a quick way to evaluate dependencies.

Hope that helps!